# Ios 7 compitible app crashes on launch. Why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, crash

I have just launched app,with IOS deplyment Target to  ios 6 and latest IOS SDK 8.1.
 Now App runs fine on ios 8 but i have some users with ios 7, saying app crashes on launch. I have checked all code ,nothing used which was deprecated. please guide me here.

I checked back in 2013 when IOS 7 launched, Many Apps was crashing, is this problem still persist?? How do i check on device with IOS 7, I did downgrade my phone's beta to IOS 7 but my app was working fine in my phone. Cant figure problem. Please some one help me.

Comment: This is a very broad question. How are we to know why your app is crashing without knowing (in great detail) the code or situations in which the crashes occur? Next time, please try and provide a more focused query with code samples.

Comment: I dont have any crash report , not showing on itune, but user told me that he tried fon 2 different device one iphone 4s and iphone 5, but on both app crashed on launch..

Comment: I come across crittercism.com just now, going to integrate it in new version but what can cause this issue

Comment: Hi I m using appirater for app review, where "[Appirater appLaunched];" on this its showing deprecated, but i have added this on last version and app was crashing before that.

Comment: on Itune it only says ..."Too few reports have been submitted for a report to be shown."

Comment: If you cant reproduce it, you cant fix it

Answer (score 2):

I have some advice for you problem.

1. You should use  https://try.crashlytics.com/ or https://mint.splunk.com/
2. Please update Project | iOS | Deployment Target 8.1
3. Please update Targets | Deployment Target 7.1

Question. when you compile your project . have you see any attention ?

good luck

Comment: No attention showing , only some on nslog statement.

Comment: why to set project and deployment Targets different?? Is it not true that Target settings over write Project settings?? Will that make any difference?? Please explain. Really appreciate your time.

Comment: App gets suspended when low memory occurs.. Can this cause app to crash on launch?? Please help me clarify here

Comment: Hello Friend, actually you should use breakpoint and check everything step by step, every method and every function.

Comment: yes but only problem is I don't have phone with IOS 7. I tried roll back to old IOS but it still runs fine on my phone with old IOS 7.

Comment: Ok. my advice is download virtual mac o.s x such as mountain lion. And you will have iOS 7 . or yoku can buy old iphone 4 device from eBay. Don't focus downgrade.

Comment: I just want to know that "App gets suspended when low memory occurs.. Can this cause any app to crash on launch??" Can it be reason in general??